# Танец и танок

Tags: этимология

Из словаря Фасмера :

> ТАНЕЦ 
> род. п. -нца, уже у Котошихина (Христиани 50), **диал. танок**, род п. -нка "хоровод", южн., зап., моск. (Даль), курск., орл., тульск., калужск. (РФВ 49, 335; ИОРЯС 3, 891), укр. танець, блр. танец. Через польск. tаniес, род. п. -nса из ср.-в.-н. tanz "танец" с введением суф. -ец в плане народн. этимологии. **Что касается -ок, ср. польск. диал. tan, tanek**...

Вот это (**русско-украинское**) "диал. *танок*" и также "польск. диал. *tan, tanek*" - происходят из средне-верхне-немецкого **tanz**??? Откуда такая уверенность, откуда такая явная "германская грусть" у этимологов. Термина "индо-германский" давно уже не существует, кстати говоря.
Танок - это хоровод, сравнительно медленный народный обрядовый танец; пляс, плясовая, как правило, достаточно быстрые "танцы" и не ритуально-обрядовые, а чисто повеселиться. Четкое разделение на *танок* и *пляс* у славян видно невооруженным глазом.

> Як **поплавом танок ведуть** дiвчата,
> Як **гопака
> сажають** парубки

Танок плавно ведут, гопака - сажают. Почему же следует славянский *танок* выводить из иностранного языка, вот вопрос.
Ваше мнение, уважаемые форумчане.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо,ни памятники древнерусской письменности, ни данные близкородственных славянских языков не в состоянии были прояснить происхождение слова ТАНЕЦ, этимологи привлекли соответствия из родственных индоевропейских языков: балтийских, индоиранских, германских, латинского, древнегреческого и др. и выявили:Франкское – dancon (тянуть, выстраиваться в линию, вытягиваться).Старофранцузское – dander (танцевать).Французское – danser (танцевать).Немецкое – tanzen (танцевать), Tanz (танец).
Польское – tanc (танец).

В русском языке слово начало употребляться с XVII в.,русское слово  было плясать Танец,танцевать было заимствовано из западноевропейских языков через польский.
Изначально существительное употреблялось с суффиксами -ок и -ей. Постепенно «танец» выделилось как литературная форма, «танок» осталось диалектным словом

А вот эзотерики усмотрели, что сочетание звуков "ТАН" соответствует эзотерическому имени звезды Антарес,которая является ярчайшей звездой в Созвездии Скорпиона . Её еще называют - красный сверхгигант. Эзотерически она отдает свой отструктурированный опыт в разные стороны, что соответствует четко продуманному и отшлифованному танцу. 
Многие древнеегипетские храмы ориентированы таким образом, что свет Антареса играл определенную роль в проходящих в них церемониях, основу которых составляли ритуальные танцы и магия. Астрологи считают, что Антарес относится к низшим проявлениям Стихии Огня и связана эта звезда с черной магией

Comment: >Франкское – dancon (тянуть,
выстраиваться в линию, вытягиваться)

Очень интересно! Давайте сопоставим славянские слова *танок* и *тянуться*, нет ли здесь какого-никакого сходства? Партнеры в танце, по крайней мере руками, завсегда друг к дружке тянутся.

Comment: Какое-никакое есть, но это будет уже не научная, а наивно-народная этимология, фантазия на тему слова, тогда и боголюбовское пойдёт: слово «танец» произошло от «таяния». Когда весной снег и лед начинали таять, образуя воду, она первая начинала движение, а вслед за пляской (читай плеском) волн происходило и дальнейшее движение  в природе.  http://bogalub.ya.ru/replies.xml?item_no=1827

Comment: Какие вы все мастера на подобные отговорки))) Респект и уважуха научным методам! Спрашиваю про танок и тянуться, отвечают : дескать, тянуть - это франкское dancon, откуда и русское диалектное **танок**... Вам, Людмила, зачет. Да, а при чем здесь "звездная магия", "таяние снегов" и "плеск волн"? Чтобы заболтать вопрос, я правильно понимаю? Двойной зачет!

Comment: Не " тянуть - это франкское dancon", а танцевать- танок от dancon-тянуть, выстраиваться в линию,  "звездная магия"- просто интересная информация на тему,а"таяние снегов" и "плеск волн"- те же фантазии, что и танок-тянуть, случайные созвучия, корни слов разные, а вот значения иногда совпадают, пересекаются.

Answer (score 0):

Господи Боже, искала адекватный ответ и кажется, кроме как здесь за 13 год и не найду уже. Как же так случилось, что у самых далёких друг от друга стран слово танец похоже? А вот оно как. Из Польского. А польский откуда?))
Спасибо тому, кто упомянул Танок из древне русского. Так же понравилось таяние движение весенних льдов. А почему нет? И всё же протоязык был нашим.
Пусть англоговорящие у себя попробуют хоть чего-то этимологию отыскать, все дороги приведут их к нам. За любое слово возьмись.
Спасибо за танец!

Answer (score 0):

тан - с польского - танец (tan), а с украинского - бой (бiй)